# Run web app front end built in reactjs on mobile

Tags: android, ios, cordova, reactjs, react-native

Lets say I have a RESTful web api as a backend, and a seperate client side react app. Ideally I'd like that react app to run on android/ios mobile devices. What are my options?

The ones I am already aware of:

1. Create a "shell" app that is basically a WebView/UIWebView that loads the web app. You could go further and add some other functionality like navigation to make the app feel more native. This would be quick to implement but the downside is the app wouldn't feel as nice as a proper native app.
2. Use Apache Cordova or similar tool (hybrid app). The advantage over WebView is that it has a standard api/set of plugins to access that allow use of device features like camera or geolocation that work across different platforms.
3. Just create a completely native app. One option would be to use react-native as this would be a similar developer experience to react, but AFAIK this would still involve the creation of a separate app - existing react code could not be re-used (is this correct?). A great user experience could be provided here but the downside would mean slower development time because another app would need to be created.

Does anyone know if there are any options I've not considered here? Also, any comments on getting some kind of code re-use between react and react-native apps would be great.

Comment: If you the architecture of your web base ReactJS app is done in such a way that the UI components are separate from your business logic you should be able to reuse at least some of your existing code in React Native. Mileage will vary depending on the architecture of your current app.